# Use OpenXml in javascript to read from excel and write to excel

Tags: javascript

I want to read excel file then validate rows & finally create an excel of incorrect rows. I want to do all this using JavaScript. This should support latest version of excel as well. What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way to do this not available at StackOverflow unless you put some efforts to do this by yourself.

Comment: I don't want the entire solution. I just want a hint